# How to upload large file in to server in java

Tags: java, rest, file-upload

How to upload large .csv file into server using java.upto 10gb  file i uploaded and when uploading large files taking so much of time.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to upload the file using Java in the first place? Please update your question with some more context.

Comment: And what have you done so far? Share some code to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

increase server timeout for the request. Rest will be taken care of Browser and OS.